# processing_state API returns "processing" even when the document is ready in Concept insight

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, concept-insights

Steps I followed:

1. First create corpus, then send create a document in it.
2. Check if the processing of the document is ready (done processing)

   `https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/concept-insights/api/v2/corpora/{account-id}/{corpus-name}/documents/{document-name}/processing_state`
3. If it is ready then i retrieve the related_concepts in the document

   `https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/concept-insights/api/v2/corpora/{account-id}/{corpus-name}/documents/{document-name}/related_concepts`

All the above steps are working (I get a 200/201 reply from Bluemix server).

The problem is in the reply of step 2. I keep getting the following response

```
{ "status": "processing", "last_modified": "2015-11-10T15:27:12.473Z" }
```

But when I do step 3, I am getting the desired response (the related concepts in the document)

```
  { 
     "concepts" : [ 
         {
            "score" : ...,
            "concept" : {
                "id": "........",
                "label": ".....

             }
          }, .....
      ]
  }
```

**UPDATE**

The processing_state API problem has been fixed. Gives the desired response

Answer (score -1):

The processing_state API problem has been fixed. Gives the desired response now.

Comment: Can you provide a summary of what you did to fix the issue so that others can make use of the knowledge? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe IBM guys did a bug fix. I tried it after a few days and boom, it worked.